# Conda not found when trying to install opencv3 in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, opencv, conda, ubuntu-18.04

I'm in the process of deciphering some code that I was given, but when I try to build the Dockerfile, I get this output halfway through:

```
Step 10/23 : RUN conda install -y -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0
 ---> Running in f08015483745
/bin/sh: 1: conda: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c conda install -y -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Here's the portion of the Dockerfile that I think contains the problem, if there even is one:

```
# Install Miniconda
RUN curl -so ~/miniconda.sh https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.5.4-Linux-x86_64.sh \
 && chmod +x ~/miniconda.sh \
 && ~/miniconda.sh -b -p ~/miniconda \
 && rm ~/miniconda.sh
ENV PATH=/home/user/miniconda/bin:$PATH
ENV CONDA_AUTO_UPDATE_CONDA=false

# Install OpenCV3 Python bindings
RUN conda install -y -c menpo opencv3=3.1.0
RUN conda clean -ya
```

Sorry if I posted this weirdly, I'm new to this :) thanks

Comment: Please put `RUN conda version` after `RUN conda clean -ya` and see whether it gives you an output.

Comment: It did the same thing, it doesn't actually get to the line after 'RUN conda clean -ya', I think it gets stuck on the line before

Comment: SOLVED: curl was returning an empty file

Comment: Yes, sometimes, docker is not easy as it seems. Need to do a lots of debug